# How converting from string to base64 works in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have some problems with converting and i don't understand it properly i think

I have user class, and in this class password is stored in byte[].

```
public partial class RegisterUser
{
    public RegisterUser()
    {
        CompanyUserOwners = new HashSet<CompanyUser>();
        ComponentSubscribers = new HashSet<ComponentSubscriber>();
        Components = new HashSet<Component>();
        GroupMemberships = new HashSet<GroupMembership>();
        Groups = new HashSet<Group>();
    }

    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    **public byte[] UserPassword { get; set; }**
    public DateTime RegisterDate { get; set; }

    public virtual CompanyUser CompanyUserUser { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CompanyUser> CompanyUserOwners { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ComponentSubscriber> ComponentSubscribers { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Component> Components { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<GroupMembership> GroupMemberships { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Group> Groups { get; set; }
}
```

Problem is, when I'm trying to convert string characters to byte[].

I use method like this to create new users:

```
public bool PostRegisterUser(string login, string password)
    {
        var bytePassword = Convert.FromBase64String(password);
        return database.CreateNewUser(login, bytePassword);
    }
```

and

```
public bool CreateNewUser(string login, byte[] password)
    {
        var newId = GetMaxRegisterUserId();
        newId++;
        AllUsers.Add(new RegisterUser()
        {
            UserId = newId,
            UserName = login,
            UserPassword = password,
            RegisterDate = DateTime.Now
        });

        return true;
    }
```

The problem is with converting. When i put for example string password "test" it goes with no problem and user is created.
But when i put "testt" for example i get this:

> System.FormatException: „The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.”

Am i missing something?

Comment: This is a bad way to store a password. I mean: DO NOT do this.

Comment: Why are you calling `FromBase64String` when you are trying to convert **to** a Base64 string?

Comment: So how can I convert string to byte[]?